# Zend Framework 1.12 and 'ContextSwitch' helper

Tags: zend-framework, context-switch

I'm writing REST api and would like to return responses in JSON format. So, I read about about 'ContextSwitch'. But I can't make it to change headers to 'application/json' and convert data to json.

Here is code of my controller:

```
 public function preDispatch()
{

    $this->getRequest()->setParam('format', 'json');
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
}


public function _init()
{

    $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
    $contextSwitch ->addActionContext('post', 'json')
                    ->initContext('json');
}

public function postAction()
{
    echo 'test';

}
```

When I check response with Curl command line tool I received:

```
< Content-Length: 4
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
test* Closing connection #0
```

Why header and data are not changed? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `_init()` method is not executed at all. Try renaming it to `init()`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in underscore.

Answer (score 0):

As i think your code has missing some steps to call context switch helper

here is working example for me to use context switch for rest api

just go throw [this API example](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/48) and make your script to work

hope this will sure help you.